# How to trigger click event when I apply checked to a radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an uninitialized property in `app.component.ts`:

```html
color!:string;
```

I want `color` to be automatically initialized when I set `checked` to a radio button:

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='red'" checked>Red
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='blue'">Blue
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='green'">Green
</div>
```

Unfortunately, `checked` does not trigger the click event so `color` is still uninitialized.  Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input()`:

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" (input)="onInput($event)">Red
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" (input)="onInput($event)">Blue
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" (input)="onInput($event)">Green
```

```js
onInput(event: Event) {
  this.color = event.target.value;
}
```

Or you can use `ngModel`:

```html
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" [(ngModel)]="color">
```

Comment: With `ngModel` then I have to initialize `color:string ="red";` (and remove `checked` because `checked` does not work anymore).